# Use Tor Browser as Default alongside Firefox in GNOME

Tags: gnome, firefox, browser, tor, .desktop

My system comes with Firefox as its browser and I have installed [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/) for my user. It took me a while to determine how to register Tor Browser as GNOME's default browser (Settings > Details > Default Applications > Web), but I was able [to accomplish it via the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/542387/39012):

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser 'Tor Browser.desktop' # or whatever name your Tor Browser Desktop file has
```

However, even after setting Tor Browser as the default Web Browser, I found that URLs from external programs were opening still in my regular (non-TOR) Firefox instance, rather than opening in Tor Browser or even starting Tor Browser if it was not running. How can I configure my account to use Tor Browser to open URLs by default, but still use normal Firefox concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser (as of Version 10) uses Firefox as a base, so essentially, you have two instances of Firefox running, and thus you are asking how to specify one instance of Firefox to handle URLs. The answer lies in the `--no-remote` argument:

```
> firefox --help | grep remote
  --no-remote        Do not accept or send remote commands; implies --new-instance.
```

You have to run the non-TOR Firefox instance with the `--no-remote` option and run Tor Browser without the `--no-remote` option (using a Tor-Browser-specific `--allow-remote` option, since Tor Browser defaults to `--no-remote`).

### Firefox

To start the non-TOR Firefox instance, I created a new [Desktop Entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) for Firefox with the `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` file as a base, but changed the following keys:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox (Yield to TOR)
Exec=firefox --no-remote %u
```

Then, I put the Desktop entry I created in my user Applications directory:

```
cp firefox-tor-friend.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

### Tor Browser

On installation, Tor Browser generates a [Desktop Entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) for itself (`~/.local/share/applications/torbrowser.desktop` or similar) with an `Exec` key value like:

```
Exec=sh -c '"/path/to/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/path/to/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
```

This command doesn't pass URLs and implicitly uses the `--no-remote` option. To enable these features, I changed the `Exec` key value to:

```
Exec=sh /path/to/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser --allow-remote %u
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --allow-remote --detach
```

The Tor Project wants every Tor Browser to look as similar as possible, so if I've compromised something by changing the `Exec` key in this way, let me know. But, use this alteration to Tor Browser at your own risk.

Having modified the [Desktop Entries](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) for both Firefox and Tor Browser, Tor Browser then handles my external URLs like I would expect.